# How to represent and query from a three entity relationship in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, database-design

I am developing a mall system where a User can have one or more shops. If you create a shop, you have the role **ADMIN** for that shop, else: you create an account then you are assigned a shop as a **MANAGER** by the **ADMIN** of that shop. A user can have a **shop** that they are an **admin**, but as well be a **manager** to a different **shop** assigned to you by an owner of a that shop. Thus, i have come up with three entities: User, Role and Shop.

***User Entity***

```
 @Entity
@Table(name = "us_users")

public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@NotBlank
private String uuid;
@Email
private String us_email;
//other fields
//getters/setters
}
```

***Role Entity.***

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ro_roles")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String rn_role_name;
//setter getter
}
```

***Shop Entity.***

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sh_shops")
public class Shop {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @NotBlank(message = "Shop name can not be left blank")
    private String sh_name;

    @NotBlank(message = "please provide shop icon")
    private String sh_icon;

    @NotBlank(message = "please fill the shop description")
    private String sh_description;
//other fields.. getters and setters
}
```

I need a relationship between these three entities: something like a table having userId,shopId,RoleId in which a user can

1. Log in the system and the system is able to determine the roles under this user and for which shop.(Using Spring security GrantedAuthorities).
2. Show the user shops under his account and the user can only operate a shop with correct role.

Kindly assist on how to model this use case. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, do you really need flexibility with the roles? Maybe having a role as a simple enum would be enough, at least if you don't plan on creating new roles at runtime. This would simplify the data model.

Second, this sounds like a map relationship for the user entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "us_users")
public class User {

    @ManyToMany
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "shop_id")
    @JoinTable(name = "user_shop_role", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Map<Shop, Role> shopRoles = new HashMap<>();

}
```

Here, you create a three-way relationship using a `user_shop_role` table containing fields `user_id`, `shop_id` and `role_id`, meaning what you'd expect.

Then adding a shop role for the user is just a matter of adding a key-value relationship to this map:

```
user.getShopRoles().put(shop, role);
```

Showing the list of shops is just iterating through the map entries and showing a shop (key) with a corresponding role (value).

Since you use `Shop` as a key, you need to make sure that the `Shop` entity implements `equals` and `hashCode` methods correctly (based on its `id`).

Comment: yes i really need flexibility with roles such that a user initially creates an account with no role associated with the account... the role is assigned after creating a shop or being assigned a shop. Login and authorization comes after these steps.

Comment: adding private Map<Shop, Role> shopRoles = new HashMap<>() to User Model would need you to have a shop that is not available during user account registration while creating your own shop.

Comment: @FredKibuchi I meant if you need the ability to create role instances at runtime (like ADMIN, MANAGER etc.) If you always have the same set of assignable roles and don't plan on adding new ones at runtime (without redeployment or adding new functionality connected to these roles), you don't need an entity for a Role - an enum will do.

Comment: @FredKibuchi you don't need to populate the map right away. You can add key/value pairs later. Initially, on user creation, the map is empty. When a user creates a shop, you add an entry with key corresponding to the newly added shop and value corresponding to the role.

Comment: a user can have more than one roles on a shop. So a key value solution will fail on this case.

Comment: @FredKibuchi so the same user may be both admin and manager for the exact same shop? I’m asking since this is not mentioned in the original problem statement, and the use case is unclear

Comment: i'm getting a null pointer exception on user.getShopRoles().put(shop, role); i'm calling this code just after saving the shop in the database. for the role i have done Role role = roleRepository.findByRoleName("ADMIN").

Comment: This can only happen if either `user` or `user.getShopRoles()` is null, which shouldn't be the case if the `shopRoles` collection was initialized with a `HashMap`.

Comment: I have your piece of code in the User model, and on my Shop service i have this while creating the shop.
`Role role = roleService.findRoleByName("ADMIN");`
`shopRepository.save(shop);`
`user.getShopRoleMap().put(shop,role );`
in that order. However, nothing is getting saved in my db. And why are we using the getter method to do map put operation? the setter method doesn't come into play?

Comment: for anyone using this as an answer note that it will only work if a user can only have one role for one shop since the map key(shop) can not be repeated twice. As well, call the userRepository.save(user) after doing map put operation. Regards